# Maven permission denied. Seems it cannot read its own SNAPSHOT file

Tags: maven

I am trying to build a project with Maven 3.5.4 and I get

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-
plugin:2.5.2:install (default-install) on project casino-static-site: 
Failed to install artifact internal.casino.flash:casino-static-
site:tar.gz:scripting:2.94-SNAPSHOT: /Users/user1/Programs/casino-
flash-binaries/site/target/casino-static-site-2.94-SNAPSHOT-
scripting.tar.gz (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]
```

I am running on **MacOS High Sierra**.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like the maven-install-plugin is unable to read your tar.gz file. What are the file permissions of casino-static-site-2.94-SNAPSHOT-
scripting.tar.gz? Does it belong to the same user as your Maven build runs? Which OS are you using?

Comment: MacOS Hight Sierra. I know it is not reading this file but this file is created by Maven. The problem is that it is creating a new one every time I run install.

Comment: Could you post your POM file?